# Check for a string in a CLOB

Tags: string, oracle, clob

i want to search for a string in a CLOB:

some thing like `id_name_2569`

i get all my IDs i need like this:

```
select project_line_id as ID
from tbl1
where art_id in (
                  select art_id
                  from tbl2
                  where type = 3
                 );
```

and i search in this table:
A1 is a CLOB field

```
select * from tbl3 where dbms_lob.instr(A1, ID)>0;
```

obviously it isnt working i know, is here a way i could do this?

Comment: bot qrys gave the same result and i made a php script to to get the results. ill accept the first answer even thought the second one is 7sec faster. :D Thank you guys learned a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this should work:

```
select tbl3.*
  from tbl1
       inner join tbl2
               on tbl2.art_id = tbl1.art_id
       inner join tbl3
               on tbl3.a1 like '%' || tbl1.project_line_id || '%'
 where tbl2.type = 3;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DBMS_LOB.instr` directly as a join condition:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT project_line_id AS ID 
          FROM tbl1 
         WHERE art_id IN (SELECT art_id FROM tbl2 WHERE TYPE = 3)) v
  JOIN tbl3 ON dbms_lob.instr(tbl3.a1, v.ID) > 0
```